# Angular 2 New router - detect 404

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, router, rc

Is it possible to detect with the new router of Angular2 if the current route exists or if it ends into a 404 error?
So I can set it back to the default route "/".

I found nothing, I searched for an hour but found only things for the deprecated router.

Comment: Does the all-catching `{ path: '/**', redirectTo: ['Home']}` not work anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this route at the *end* of your Routes which means Angular 2 RC1 router will go to this MyDefaultComponent if none of the other defined routes matches the requested URL:

```
{ path: '**', component: MyDefaultComponent }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wildcard to do that and either redirect to any other route or have a 404 component for that:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'Welcome', component: WelcomeComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/products', name: 'Products', component: ProductListComponent },
    { path: '/product/:id', name: 'ProductDetail',  component: ProductDetailComponent },

    // Redirect option:
    // { path: '/**', redirectTo:['Welcome'] },

    // Not found component option:
    // {path: '/**', component: NotFoundComponent},

    // Both together:
    { path: '/not-found', name: 'NotFound', component: NotFoundComponent},
    { path: '/**', redirectTo:['NotFound'] },
])
```

Note that in the version of Angular that I'm using right now, `2.0.0-beta.15`, if you put just `path: '/*'` it won't work, [see here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4055).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The only way to do in angular 2 as per latest doc is

1. Redirect to **pagenotfound** when route doesn't match with any pattern

> {
>         path: '**',
>         redirectTo: 'pagenotfound'
>       }

2. Navigate to component without URL change

> {
>         path: '**',
>         component: SomeComponent
>       }